# Combinatorics - 6 girls arranged in 2 rows ( each row contains at least 1 girl)

Tags: combinatorics

6 girls are arranged into 2 rows. Given that each row contain at least 1 girl, find the number of the possible combination(s)

My solution:
Using the concept of repeated combinations,

$_{2+4-1} C _{4} $

=$_5C_4$

=5

(The answer key says it is 2160, can someone please explain?)

Comment: "Given that each row contains at least 1 girl.." Isn't it obvious and unavoidable that every row contains exactly 3 girls here?

Comment: $5$ is way too small.  Even if I put $5$ in one row and $1$ in the other, that's $6$ ways to do it.

Comment: @drhab The question might allow a row of 4 and a row of 2!

Comment: @drhab can't it be 1 for row 1, and 5 for row 2?
I also listed it this way : (1,5)(2,4)(3,3)(4,2)(5,1)

Comment: Mind you, $2160$ seems far too large.  I'd have said the answer was $\sum_{i=1}^5\binom 6i=62$.

Comment: Yes, you (and @ParclyTaxel) are right. So the condition is that the rows are not empty, right?

Comment: Oh, I see why you said $5$.  I am assuming the girls are distinguishable.  That is, I think the arrangements $(ABCDE,F)$ and $(ABCDF,E)$ are different.

Comment: As @lulu remarks: the girl are distinghuishable (I never met girls that where not).

Comment: And, as @RossMillikan points out, if we assume that they are distinguishing between orders, so row $AB$ is not the same as row $BA$ then you clearly get $3600$ which is too great.  I think it is a waste of time to try to guess what the writers of this problem had in mind...reverse engineering appears not to be working,

Comment: What is the most logically correct answer assuming the answer key was not given?

Comment: If we distinguish between the rows, the logically correct answer is $3600$.  If we do not distinguish between the rows, it is $1800$.

Answer (score 1):

They are considering different orders of girls to be different.  You can imagine putting the girls in one row in $6!=720$ ways then choosing a point to split the rows in five ways.  That would give $3600$ possibilities.  They may be thinking that $ABC/DEF$ is the same as $DEF/ABC$ but that only deducts $360$ leaving $3240$.  I can't get to $2160$.

Comment: The $3600$ is correct if there is a "front" row and a "back" row. You can get $2160$ if you don't distinguish between the rows.

Comment: @BarryCipra:  if there isn't a front and back row it seems to divide the $3600$ by $2$ giving $1800$.  I can't find the other $360$ then.

Comment: @BarryCipra When I considered the possibility that the rows were not distinguishable, I also got $1800$.   Let's say Alice is one of the girls.  There are $\binom{5}{k}$ ways to choose which $k$ of the other five girls are in the same row as Alice, $(k + 1)!$ ways to arrange the students in her row, and $[6 - (k + 1)]! = (5 - k)!$ ways to arrange the students in the other row, for a total of $$\sum_{k = 0}^{4} \binom{5}{k}(k + 1)!(5 - k)! = 1800$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig (and Ross), you are both quite right.  What I should have said is, you get $2160$ if you never allow the back row to be shorter than the front row.  So once you've got $ABCDEF$ as one of the $720$ line-ups, you split after either $A$, $B$, or $C$ (with $DEF$ at least going to the back row).